# How to Make a Clickable Sprite in Unity 2D, detect if the cursor is hovering over a sprite, and how to change scene with code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click

I am making a 2D game in unity, and I want a start screen, but I cant find out how to make the start button clickable, and to then change the scene to level 1

The game will be a cursor labyrinth, so any help with detecting if a mouse is hovering over something would be appreciated

I looked up a bunch of tutorials but none of them worked in c#

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:**

You will have to add a **Button** Component to the sprite.

Alternatively, you can right click in the Scene Hierarchy and go to Create -> UI -> Button. This automatically creates a simple Button for you. Then it sprites can be changed accordingly.

**STEP 2:**

Then assign callback to the Button in the OnClick() Field to make it interactable. To load the scene,
Create a new C# script. Make a new method in it. Use the [LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) method in SceneManagement class. Then the script becomes:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ExampleScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Loadscene(int sceneIndex)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go bro.

> public bool IsOverUi()
> {
> var eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current)
> {
> position = Input.mousePosition
> };
> var results = new List();
> EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
> return results.Count > 0;
> }

Answer (score 0):

Following the Answer here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1199251/onmouseover-ui-button-c.html

You can add a script:

```
public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler{
     

     public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         //do stuff
     }
}
```